RMS Velocity of Gases
Whenever we have to find the RMS velocity of gas we use the formula √3RT/M, where R is the ideal gas constant, T is the absolute temperature and M refers to the molar mass of that particular gas. However, sometimes, the formula √3KT/M, where K is Boltzman constant, is also used. I just don't know when this second form is used. Please help me clear that out.

The second form is equivalent to the first form, but $M$ (perhaps better written as $m$) in the second form refers to the mass of an individual atom. You can recover the second form from the first form by using $R=N_Ak_B$, where $N_A$ is Avogadro's number and $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant:
$$
\frac{R}{M}
=\frac{N_Ak_B}{M}
=\frac{k_B}{M/N_A}
=\frac{k_B}{m}
$$
since
$$
\left[\frac{M}{N_A}\right]
=\frac{\mbox{kg}}{\mbox{mol}}\times\frac{\mbox{mol}}{\mbox{atom}}
=\frac{\mbox{kg}}{\mbox{atom}}
=\left[m\right]
$$
and $[\cdot]$ means "the units of".

So, please tell me if I am getting it right that M in the first form is the molar mass of gas ( let's take an example of oxygen gas) is 32 grams, whereas in second form it's 32 amu or 32 * 1.67 * 10^(-24) grams.

@Physics_enthus That’s correct, just remember to convert both masses to kilograms or use units of the ideal gas constant and Boltzmann constant that are consistent with a mass measured in grams.
